# Can flavor changing neutral currents occur

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, weak-interaction

It says that flavor changing neutral currents are impossible. However I am just asking what would happen if a top quark emits a Z boson or a Higgs boson.

Comment: Neither of those are flavor-changing neutral currents. A top quark that emits a Z or a Higgs is still a top quark, just like an electron that emits a photon is still an electron.

Comment: If a top quark emits a Z boson then it might change flavor, right because then the mass of the top quark will be so low that it might overlap with the masses of the up quark or the charm quark. The only major difference between top quark, up quark, and charm quark are there masses.

Comment: No, it doesn't. $t\to Zu$ has never been observed, nor is it predicted to be observed. That reaction vertex is simply not included in the Standard Model.

Comment: The top, up, and charm quarks differ in their flavor as well. Electromagnetism, the strong interaction, $Z$ boson exchange, and Higgs exchange all conserve flavor. The _only_ interaction that does not is $W$ boson exchange.

Comment: Also, the emission of a $Z$ boson does not change the mass of the top quark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: *Tree-level* flavour changing neutral currents are not allowed in the Standard Model. There could be, if you invent another particle or two (and indeed there are New Physics proposals about this). 
 But the Standard model *does* allow for flavour changing neutral currents with higher order diagrams, like *box* or *penguin* diagrams.

**More in depth**

A "flavour changing current" is a process featuring the violation of quark flavour conservation. When mediated by a *neutral* particle such as the $Z^0$ boson (or a photon), they do not entail a net charge exchange and are hence called "flavour changing *neutral* currents".

> if a top quark emits a Z boson or a Higgs boson

At tree level the $Z^0$ boson *cannot* allow flavour mixing.

This is because the $Z^0$ boson has no charge and can hence only couple quarks of the same charge: so both $i$ and $j$ have to be $\in (u, c, t)$ or $\in (d, s, b)^\dagger$. You can show, then, the matrix element for the tree level interaction goes as :
$$ \mathcal{M} \quad \propto \quad g_W \cdot(u, c, t)  \left (\begin{array}{c} \bar u \\ \bar c \\ \bar t  \end{array} \right ) \quad \propto \quad u\bar u + c \bar c + d \bar d,$$
i.e. no cross-generational coupling and hence no flavour mixing.

If the process were mediated by a $W^{\pm}$ boson, on the other hand, you'd have something like:
$$ \mathcal{M} \quad \propto \quad \bar u\bar V_{ud} d + \bar u V_{us} s + ...,$$
i.e. cross-generational coupling and hence flavour mixing. 
 $V$ is the [CKM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix#CKM_matrix) matrix.

Hence, the lowest order diagrams for Flavour Changing Neutral Currents in the Standard Model are *box* or *penguin* diagrams:
[image]

The *penguin diagram* gets its name because:

[image]

---

$\dagger$: There are some subtleties about the mass eigenstates $(d,s,b)$ not being the same eigenstates of the weak force $(d',s',b')$. The two bases are related by the CKM matrix. I ignore all of this, just to provide a qualitative picture.