# Can $Z$ bosons mediate short-range forces between electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction

The flavor quantum numbers and charge of $Z$ bosons should allow it to mediate between electrons without violating any conservation rules. So at very short displacement scales do electrons actually attract each other through mediating $Z$ bosons?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/neucur.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $Z$ bosons can mediate electron-electron scattering $e e \rightarrow e e$, and electron-positron pair production $Z\rightarrow e^+ e^-$.

As to whether the force is repulsive or attractive, see this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77200).

Comment: Really nice answer. Can you please provide some reference for this: "Z  bosons can mediate electron-electron scattering ee→ee, and electron-positron pair production Z→e+e−."

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei I would have to google for a reference for what I specifically said. But those comments are pretty straightforward: the $Z$ boson couples to anything that has weak hypercharge and weak isospin (and electrons/positrons do), but *cannot* change lepton flavour, at least not in the [standard model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/549535). Hence it can only do scattering and pair production, and the OP had asked specifically only about electrons.

Answer (score 0):

SLAC E158 measured parity violation in polarized Møller scattering ($\vec e^-e^-\rightarrow e^-e^-$). The beam electron is longitudinally polarized. The 1st order diagrams include t and u channel photon exchange and Z$^0$ exchange. Their interference is parity violating, leading to a left/right asymmetry in the scattering cross section.

Note that this scattering is far off the Z-pole; likewise, parity violation in atomic cesium ($Q_W$) is sensitive to Z exchange in an atom, so the "very short displacement scales" is not necessary.